# Jira python calculate time

Tags: python, jira, python-jira

I am trying to calculate the time from the issue is created and until it is resolved. With these fields:

```
creation_time = issue.fields.created
resolved_time = issue.fields.resolutiondate
```

Output when I print:

```
Creation: 2016-06-09T14:37:05.000+0200 Resolved: 2016-06-10T10:53:12.000+0200
```

Is there anyway I can minus the resolution date and time with the creation date and time to find how much time is spent on a issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parse the date/time strings into a suitable datetime object and then you can use those to do calculations.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime) explains how to parse a date/time string or you can just take a look at the [documentation for the strptime() method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).

For calculations, there are examples in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750644/how-to-use-python-to-calculate-time) and there's detailed documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html).

As an example, something like this should be close to a solution:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

createdTime = datetime.strptime('2016-06-09T14:37:05.000+0200', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
resolvedTime = datetime.strptime('2016-06-10T10:53:12.000+0200', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')

duration = resolvedTime - createdTime
```

*duration* will be a *timedelta* object and you can access *duration.days*, *duration.seconds* and *duration.microseconds* to get its info.

*strptime* does have as a drawback that it does not support parsing timezones, so you'll have to cut that part of your input first. Alternatively, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12281975/convert-timestamps-with-offset-to-datetime-obj-using-strptime).

Comment: How will that be in my case?

Comment: Added an example that should be close to what you need.

Comment: I receive this error `ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'` Maye `dateutil` is more sufficient to use(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571419/python-parsing-a-datetime-with-a-timezone)

Comment: Turns out strptime doesn't handle timezones. I've updated the answer and added another link to a post with a solution.

Answer (score 1):

strptime does not support parsing timezones.
This code is working for me

```
from datetime import datetime
createdTime = datetime.strptime(issue.fields.created.split(".")[0], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
resolvedTime = datetime.strptime(issue.fields.resolutiondate.split(".")[0], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
duration = resolvedTime - createdTime
```

Answer (score 0):

I've write a function which calculates mean, median and variance of the respond times in days. Hope that helps;

```
import datetime as d
import numpy as np

ymd_create = []
ymd_resdate = []
delta_t = []

class calculate:
    def __init__(self):
        self.result = 0

    def meantime(self, issueobject):
        for i in range(0, len(issueobject)):
            ymd_create.append(d.datetime(int(issueobject[i].raw[u'fields'][u'created'].split('T')[0].split('-')[0]), int(issueobject[i].raw[u'fields'][u'created'].split('T')[0].split('-')[1]), int(issueobject[i].raw[u'fields']
                                                                                                                                                                                                     [u'created'].split('T')[0].split('-')[2]), int(issueobject[i].raw[u'fields'][u'created'].split('T')[1].split(':')[0]), int(issueobject[i].raw[u'fields'][u'created'].split('T')[1].split(':')[1])))
            ymd_resdate.append(d.datetime(int(issueobject[i].raw[u'fields'][u'resolutiondate'].split('T')[0].split('-')[0]), int(issueobject[i].raw[u'fields'][u'resolutiondate'].split('T')[0].split('-')[1]), int(issueobject[i].raw[u'fields']
                                                                                                                                                                                                                    [u'resolutiondate'].split('T')[0].split('-')[2]), int(issueobject[i].raw[u'fields'][u'resolutiondate'].split('T')[1].split(':')[0]), int(issueobject[i].raw[u'fields'][u'resolutiondate'].split('T')[1].split(':')[1])))
            delta_t.append((ymd_resdate[i] - ymd_create[i]).days)

        self.result = np.mean(np.array(delta_t))
        return self.result

    def mediantime(self, issueobject):
        for i in range(0, len(issueobject)):
            ymd_create.append(d.datetime(int(issueobject[i].raw[u'fields'][u'created'].split('T')[0].split('-')[0]), int(issueobject[i].raw[u'fields'][u'created'].split('T')[0].split('-')[1]), int(issueobject[i].raw[u'fields']
                                                                                                                                                                                                     [u'created'].split('T')[0].split('-')[2]), int(issueobject[i].raw[u'fields'][u'created'].split('T')[1].split(':')[0]), int(issueobject[i].raw[u'fields'][u'created'].split('T')[1].split(':')[1])))
            ymd_resdate.append(d.datetime(int(issueobject[i].raw[u'fields'][u'resolutiondate'].split('T')[0].split('-')[0]), int(issueobject[i].raw[u'fields'][u'resolutiondate'].split('T')[0].split('-')[1]), int(issueobject[i].raw[u'fields']
                                                                                                                                                                                                                    [u'resolutiondate'].split('T')[0].split('-')[2]), int(issueobject[i].raw[u'fields'][u'resolutiondate'].split('T')[1].split(':')[0]), int(issueobject[i].raw[u'fields'][u'resolutiondate'].split('T')[1].split(':')[1])))
            delta_t.append((ymd_resdate[i] - ymd_create[i]).days)

        self.result = np.median(np.array(delta_t))
        return self.result

    def variancetime(self, issueobject):
        for i in range(0, len(issueobject)):
            ymd_create.append(d.datetime(int(issueobject[i].raw[u'fields'][u'created'].split('T')[0].split('-')[0]), int(issueobject[i].raw[u'fields'][u'created'].split('T')[0].split('-')[1]), int(issueobject[i].raw[u'fields']
                                                                                                                                                                                                     [u'created'].split('T')[0].split('-')[2]), int(issueobject[i].raw[u'fields'][u'created'].split('T')[1].split(':')[0]), int(issueobject[i].raw[u'fields'][u'created'].split('T')[1].split(':')[1])))
            ymd_resdate.append(d.datetime(int(issueobject[i].raw[u'fields'][u'resolutiondate'].split('T')[0].split('-')[0]), int(issueobject[i].raw[u'fields'][u'resolutiondate'].split('T')[0].split('-')[1]), int(issueobject[i].raw[u'fields']
                                                                                                                                                                                                                    [u'resolutiondate'].split('T')[0].split('-')[2]), int(issueobject[i].raw[u'fields'][u'resolutiondate'].split('T')[1].split(':')[0]), int(issueobject[i].raw[u'fields'][u'resolutiondate'].split('T')[1].split(':')[1])))
            delta_t.append((ymd_resdate[i] - ymd_create[i]).days)

        self.result = np.var(np.array(delta_t))
        return self.result
```