# Detect and kick alts using discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to make a moderating bot that kicks alt accounts (accounts that are younger than 10 days)I have `whois` command but it only shows when account was created:

```
@client.command(name="whois", aliases=["memberinfo"])
async def whois(ctx, member:discord.Member =  None):

    

    if member is None:
        member = ctx.author
        roles = [role for role in ctx.author.roles]

    else:
        roles = [role for role in member.roles]

    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"{member}", colour=member.colour, timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)
    embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested by: {ctx.author}", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    embed.set_author(name="User Info: ")
    embed.add_field(name="ID:", value=member.id, inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="User Name:",value=member.display_name, inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Discriminator:",value=member.discriminator, inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Current Status:", value=str(member.status).title(), inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Current Activity:", value=f"{str(member.activity.type).title().split('.')[1]} {member.activity.name}" if member.activity is not None else "None", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Created At:", value=member.created_at.strftime("%a, %d, %B, %Y, %I, %M, %p UTC"), inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Joined At:", value=member.joined_at.strftime("%a, %d, %B, %Y, %I, %M, %p UTC"), inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name=f"Roles [{len(roles)}]", value=" **|** ".join([role.mention for role in roles]), inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Top Role:", value=member.top_role, inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Bot?:", value=member.bot, inline=False)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    return
```

How can I make something like:

```
if member < 10 days:
    await member.kick
    await channel.send('Detected alt account and kicked it')
```

I also don't want full code. I need only explanation how to do this. Thank you

Comment: Maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750644/how-to-use-python-to-calculate-time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`discord.Member` has the attribute `created_at` which returns a `datetime.datetime` instance, you can get the delta days by subtracting today's date and using the `days` attribute

```py
created = member.created_at
now = datetime.now() # remember to `from datetime import datetime`
delta = (now - created).days

if delta < 10:
    await member.kick()
    await channel.send('Detected alt account and kicked it')
```

#### Reference:

- [`Member.created_at`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User.created_at)
- [`datetime.datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime)

Comment: Thank you sir, I will check it out.

Comment: Alright:) remember to accept the answer if it helped

Comment: If I'm not wrong, `created_at` will return a `datetime` object pointing to a certain date, and `days` is supposed to return what he is looking for when it is used with a `timedelta` object instead.

Comment: yes, my bad that's right. Ill edit my answer

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński I guess it would work but how can I define member in on_member_join event? also how can I define guild? I know that I require a lot but I really cant handle it. Thanks

Comment: Yes, it will work, the code will pretty much look the same, the guild would be `member.guild` in that case

Comment: Class member has no 'guild' member
Class member has no 'created_at' member

Comment: It has, [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.guild), you're doing something wrong

Comment: Should I add my current code to the post?

Answer (score 1):

From the discord.py documentation, you can use the `created_at` attribute of a `discord.User` or `discord.Member` class. It will return a `datetime.datetime` object.

```py
>>> myaccount.created_at
datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 6, 14, 22, 14)
```

Then you could simply take another `datetime` object for now and substract one from the other:

```py
import datetime as datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
if (now - myaccount.created_at).days > 10
    await member.kick()
    await channel.send('Detected alt account and kicked it')
```